# Test-NetConnection problem with ConstrainInterface

Tags: powershell, tcp, powershell-cmdlet, netconnection

How check communication between two another interface different than data?
For example I want check communication TCP between two voice interfaces. NOT Ping.
Source IP is 10.116.69.215
Destination IP is 10.104.74.145
Previosly I tried:

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 5060 -ComputerName 10.104.74.145
```

But I receive only summary from interface data.

```
ComputerName           : 10.104.74.145
RemoteAddress          : 10.104.74.145
RemotePort             : 5060
InterfaceAlias         : VMAccess
SourceAddress          : 10.116.64.202
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

I tried modify cmdlet. So I began from
Get-NetAdapter

```
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------
BackupNet                 Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #3         15 Up
VoiceNet                  Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #4         17 Up
VMAccess                  Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2         14 Up
BootNet                   Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter            13 Not Present
```

**Test-NetConnection 10.104.74.145 -Port 5060 -ConstrainInterface 17 -DiagnoseRouting -InformationLevel Detailed**

but I receive:

```
Test-NetConnection : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConstrainInterface'.
At line:1 char:45
+ ... st-netconnection 10.102.73.135 -Port 5060 -ConstrainInterface 17 -Dia ...
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-NetConnection], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Test-NetConnection
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can't use -port with that parameter set.

```
Test-NetConnection
    [[-ComputerName] <String>]
    [-DiagnoseRouting]
    [-ConstrainSourceAddress <String>]
    [-ConstrainInterface <UInt32>]
    [-InformationLevel <String>]
    [<CommonParameters>]
```